# A problem about the limit of a sequence having to do with the partial sums of another sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, power-series

Let us suppose that  $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}}$ is a sequence of positive real numbers and that the sequence $s_{0}, s_{1}, s_{2}, \ldots$ is defined by $s_{k}=a_{0}+\ldots+a_{k}$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$.

Let us suppose that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \ln \left(\frac{s_{k+1}}{s_{k-1}}\right)=0$ and that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \ln(s_{k+1}s_{k})=\ell$ for a certain real number $\ell$.

Do the previous conditions are sufficient to guarantee that the sequence $\{\ln (s_{k})\}$ has a limit as $k \to \infty$?

Thanks in advance for your comments and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(s_k)$ is an increasing sequence and so is $(\ln (s_k))$. So we only have to check if this sequence is bounded. Suppose $\ln (s_k) \to \infty$. Then $\ln (s_{k+1}s_k) =\ln (s_{k+1})+\ln (s_k) \to \infty$ contradicting the hypothesis. Hence $(\ln (s_k))$ is convergent.

Comment: Cool! Thanks a bunch, Kavi Rama Murthy...

Comment: Kavi: Don't we need a hypothesis of the type $\ln (s_{k})>0$ for every suff. large $k$ in order to guarantee that $\ln (s_{k}) \to \infty$?

Comment: @Jamai-Con Logarithm is increasing. So $\ln (s_k)$ is increasing. To prove by contradiction that it is convergent we **assume** that $\ln (s_k)$ tends to $\infty$. So there is no need to prove before hand that $\ln (s_k) >0$.

Comment: I see ..........